# Run deck Automation script

Tags: shell

I need a help, I am trying to write bash/shell script which will be placed in Rundeck tool. As my org has more than 10,000 severs Ec2. This is what I am expecting.

1. script to login into Ec2.
2. show output of df -h,lsblk & Java version.

Please anyone help me with the script.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(questioners should post their tried code/script and add it in their question), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the EC2 nodes on Rundeck using a [model source](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/resource-model-sources/#node-model-sources). To avoid configuring each EC2 node you can use the EC2 Model Source Plugin, take a look at [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin) (check [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html#installing-plugins) to learn how to install plugins on Rundeck), after that you can create a [job](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/04-jobs.html#jobs) with an [inline script](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#script-step) step using a [node filter](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/11-node-filters.html#node-filters) pointing to your ec2 nodes.

Comment: 1) Configured rundeck into ec2. 
2) Created job as well. 
3) I would like to see one of my ec2 disk space ( df -h ) by using script can you please provide me sample script.